Spring does not deactivate Sockjs Heartbeats, which leads to double heartbeats, from Sockjs AND Stomp
I am right in the middle of a deep dive into how stomp and sockjs handle the provision of heartbeats.
If I understand correct sockjs is responsible for the provision of heartbeats if .withSockJS() is set on an endpoint and no task scheduler is configured for the broker.
Example:
class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker(...);
        [...]
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint(WebSocketConfiguration.BASE_PATH).withSockJS();
    }
}

If I register a TaskScheduler stomp will be responsible for providing heartbeats.
registry.enableSimpleBroker(...).setTaskScheduler(this.threadPoolTaskScheduler)
As expected heartbeats over sockjs are now disabled and are provided via stomp with the default interval 10000, 10000. As per documentation "First number represents how often the server will write or send a heartbeat. The second is how often the client should write."
But now comes the part I don't understand. If I don't want the client to write heartbeats and therefore set the heartbeat values like this: .setHeartbeatValue(new long[] { 25_000, 0 }), serverside heartbeats over sockjs are NOT disabled!
This results in BOTH stomp AND sockjs sending heartbeats to the client.
Diving into the spring source code I found the StompSubProtocollHandler.afterStompSessionConnected method to be responsible for disabling sockjs heartbeats:
private StompHeaderAccessor afterStompSessionConnected(Message<?> message, StompHeaderAccessor accessor,
WebSocketSession session) {
    [...]

    long[] heartbeat = accessor.getHeartbeat();
    if (heartbeat[1] > 0) {
        session = WebSocketSessionDecorator.unwrap(session);
        if (session instanceof SockJsSession) {
            ((SockJsSession) session).disableHeartbeat();
        }
    }

    return accessor;
}

Why does the disabling of sockjs heartbeats depend on the client side heartbeat interval?
